# What sort of tests does POST run on ram?

Tags: memory, bios, post

This is loosely related to a homework assignment I'm currently doing, for a part of it I am trying to work out what sort of memory tests a standard POST test will run on ram, i.e: the ways it will attempt to write/read from the memory, I'm unable to find anything on this on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

It the past, the BIOS had options for extended memory tests.  Today as little as possible is performed in order to minimize the time it takes for the computer the start.  Generally, it only checks what the memory is.  The method for this is called [Serial Presence Detect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect).

Comment: Thank you, isn't there a way in the BIOS that you can trigger more extensive diagnostic tests for the RAM to run on the next cold boot?

Comment: Windows can, and many computer manufacturers add diagnostic partitions which can.